# draw CALayer into a CGContext

Tags: calayer, cgcontext

I have the following code:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSaveGState(context);

CALayer *sublayer = [CALayer layer];
sublayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
sublayer.cornerRadius = 20.0;
sublayer.frame = CGRectMake(20, 0, 300, 20);

[sublayer setNeedsDisplay];
[sublayer drawInContext:context];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
```

But when i view the return newImage, there is just an empty image. When i change drawInContext to renderInContext, then i got the above sublayer, but it seems like the coordinate system is mess up.

Any idea why drawInContext on the above did not work?

Answer (score 11):

Try using `renderInContext` in place of `drawInContext`.

My understanding is that `drawInContext` is there to be overridden, whereas `renderInContext` is used to render the contents of a layer to the context.

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/):

> **`- drawInContext:`**
>
> The default implementation of this method does not doing any drawing itself. If the layer’s delegate implements the `drawLayer:inContext:` method, that method is called to do the actual drawing.
>
> Subclasses can override this method and use it to draw the layer’s content. When drawing, all coordinates should be specified in points in the logical coordinate space.

> **`- renderInContext:`**
>
> This method renders directly from the layer tree, ignoring any animations added to the render tree. Renders in the coordinate space of the layer.

Comment: You are awesome.

Comment: THIS !! If your backgroundColor, borderColor or other properties are not working, this is the solution. You deserve to win a lottery ticket.

Answer (score 3):

The coordinate system isn't messed up, per se. Quartz uses a different coordinate system than UIKit. In Quartz, the Y-axis originates at the bottom-left of the framing rectangle. The values become larger as you travel farther "up" the rectangle. For a visual representation, see the documentation at

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html

This differs from UIKit in that UIKit's coordinate system origin is the top-left with y-axis values becoming more positive as you travel "down".

As for why drawInContext: doesn't work, you should also reference the docs for the CALayer class where it says, "Default implementation does nothing."

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html